# RAM Usage keeps increasing in Flask-SocketIO

Tags: flask, websocket, memory-leaks, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am working on a web app where I need to capture video feed which I am doing with JavaScript and sending the video frame by frame to the flask backend through SocketIO. On getting the frame, I am doing a simple inference from a deep learning model on the image.
The problem is, the RAM usage of the server is increasing rapidly after receiving the messages emitted from the javascript client.

Here is the code of my flask backend:

```
@socketio.on('input image', namespace='/test')
 def test_message(input):
#socketio.wait(seconds=2)
# name_emotion = []
today = date.today()
# print("Here")
input = input.split(",")[1]
# camera.enqueue_input(input)
image_data = input
# time.sleep(10)
global name_emotion
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48,48,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

model.load_weights('model.h5')
img = imread(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(image_data)))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = facecasc.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    # print('Infaces')
    cv2.rectangle(gray, (x, y-50), (x+w, y+h+10), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cropped_img = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(cv2.resize(roi_gray, (48, 48)), -1), 0)
    prediction = model.predict(cropped_img)
```

Here is the code of my Javascript Client:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
let namespace = "/test";
let video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
 let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvasElement");
// let canvas = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
photo = document.getElementById('photo');
var localMediaStream = null;

var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + 
namespace);

function sendSnapshot() {
 if (!localMediaStream) {
  return;
 }

ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight, 0, 0, 300, 150);

let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
socket.emit('input image', dataURL);
// socket.wait(seconds=2)

//socket.emit('output image')

//var img = new Image();
//socket.on('out-image-event',function(data){


//img.src = dataURL//data.image_data
//photo.setAttribute('src', data.image_data);

//});


}

//socket.on('connect', function() {
//console.log('Connected!');
//});

var constraints = {
  video: {
  width: { min: 640 },
  height: { min: 480 }
}
};
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
video.srcObject = stream;
localMediaStream = stream;

  setInterval(function () {
  sendSnapshot();
  }, 50);
 }).catch(function(error) {
console.log(error);
 });
 });
```

Can anyone please help me where the problem seems to be?

Comment: You are doing things that require heavy use of RAM, so why do you think this is not expected? You are sending 20 images per second. Is the server able to keep up with that rate?

Comment: Yes, I understand but should'nt flask release memory after each message being processed?

Comment: Flask is not using the memory. The other libraries that you use are.